# Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM) WebSocket code connecting twice on iOS

Tags: kotlin, websocket, coroutine, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I'm working on a Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM) project where I'm using WebSockets to send and receive messages. I have been following the ktor client and server guides for a simple chat app. Everything works as expected on Android but on iOS two users are created every time an iOS client connects to the server. This means iOS receives every message twice and is noticed by the server twice as two different user ids.

client: https://ktor.io/docs/getting-started-ktor-client-chat.html#wire-it-together
server: https://ktor.io/docs/creating-web-socket-chat.html

Server code:

```
class Connection(val session: DefaultWebSocketSession) {
    companion object {
        val lastId = AtomicInteger(0)
    }
    val name = "user${lastId.getAndIncrement()}"
}

fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val server = embeddedServer(Netty, 13276, watchPaths = emptyList()) {
        install(WebSockets) {
            pingPeriod = Duration.ofSeconds(15)
            timeout = Duration.ofSeconds(15)
            maxFrameSize = Long.MAX_VALUE
            masking = false
        }

        routing {
            get("/") {
                call.respondText("All good here in ", ContentType.Text.Plain)
            }
            val connections = Collections.synchronizedSet<Connection?>(LinkedHashSet())

            webSocket("/ws") {
                println("Adding user!")
                val thisConnection = Connection(this)
                connections += thisConnection
                try {
                    send(Frame.Text("You are connected! There are ${connections.count()} users here."))
                    connections.forEach {
                        if (it != thisConnection)
                            it.session.send(Frame.Text("${thisConnection.name} Connected"))
                    }
                    for (frame in incoming) {
                        frame as? Frame.Text ?: continue
                        val receivedText = frame.readText()
                        val textWithUsername = "[${thisConnection.name}]: $receivedText"
                        connections.forEach {
                            it.session.send(Frame.Text(textWithUsername))
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    println(e.localizedMessage)
                } finally {
                    println("Removing $thisConnection!")
                    connections -= thisConnection
                }
            }
        }
    }
    server.start(wait = true)
}
```

Client Code:

```
private fun clientMain() {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        delay(2000)
        runBlocking {
            client.webSocket("ws://$localIp:13276/ws") {
                send(Frame.Text("Test Message"))
                for (frame in incoming)
                    println((frame as Frame.Text).readText())
            }
        }
        client.close()
        println("Connection closed. Goodbye!")
    }
}
```

Expected:

```
You are connected! There are 1 users here.
[user0]: Test Message
```

Actual:

```
You are connected! There are 1 users here.
[user0]: Test Message
user1 Connected
You are connected! There are 2 users here.
[user1]: Test Message
[user1]: Test Message
```

The client code is just a test that replicates the issue easily, not the real chat listening client. I have tested that without the coroutine wrapper and only using the run blocker, it does successfully only connect once on the kmm iOS code. That however runs on the main thread and the app is unusable when the websocket is in a while loop listening like a normal chat app. I suspect that the Dispatcher.Default is acting in a way different than android as it might not be a true coroutine on the iOS side. How can I connect an iOS device just once to the server using a coroutine so the main thread is not blocked?

Comment: are you sure `clientMain` is not called twice? try adding some logs before `client.webSocket`, I can't think of an other explanation. also you should be able to remove `runBlocking` safely, since `client.webSocket` is already a suspend call